# node JS server connection

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to use the code below but it doesn't work for me because the server doesn't connect and there's no error in the console.

```
var PORT=8080;
var http=require('http');
var http=require('swig');
var http=require('url');

exports.startServer=function (PORT){
var server=http.createServer(function(req,res){
var page=url.parse(req.url).pathname;
if(page=='/'){
res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'text/html'});
res.write(swig.renderFile('templates/home.tpl',{
name :'user'

})
);
} else{
    res.writeHead(404,{'Content-Type':'text/html'});
    res.writeHead('<h1>Error 404 : page not found</h1>');
}
res.end();

});
server.listen(PORT);
console.log('Server running on'+ PORT);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason I think is that you have assigned the variable `http` for three times, which makes that only the last one takes effect.

Try to replace

```
var http=require('http');
var http=require('swig');
var http=require('url');
```

with

```
var http=require('http');
var swig=require('swig');
var url=require('url');
```

Answer (score 0):

**check any other server running on same port or not**

*if it is running, change port number*

```
var port = process.env.PORT | 3000;
```

**change this**

```
var http=require('http');
var swig=require('swig');
var url=require('url');
```

> Better to use express.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT | 3000;
var server = app.listen(port,'0.0.0.0',function(){
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log("Server listen to : "+host+":"+port);
});
```